# Android - display specific contacts information

Tags: android, android-intent, contacts

In my application when a user clicks on a button I want to open the contacts application and display a particular contacts information.

At the minute I have this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, People.CONTENT_URI);
startActivity(intent);
```

This displays the contact application with all the contacts displayed.

But how do I get it to display just one contact according to the contacts name or number?

This Code works: (answer)

```
Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(People.CONTENT_URI, 23);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, contactUri);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append the contact ID number to the end of the URI.

For instance *content://contacts/people/615*

or People.CONTENT_URI + "/" + contactId

The ID number will come from your original contact query.

Comment: I cant append a string or int to the Uri though? Nor can I use the String "content://contacts/people/615" as an argument for the intent?

Comment: Got it using this - Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId
             (People.CONTENT_URI, 23); Thanks

Comment: Yes, my apologies, my snippet won't actually compile. Glad you got it working.